# How to hide Caption Image in Blog Feed?

Tags: blogger

In the post, I added a Caption Image like this image. How do you prevent the Caption from appearing in the Snippet in the blog feed? I tried to hide it on homepage with this code but it's not working. Is there any solution?

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'> .image-credit {display:none;} </b:if>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtG4u.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XeAu.jpg)

I hope you can help me.